# Making UIProgressView smoother

Tags: ios, swift3, uiprogressview

I have implemented a `UIProgressView` which goes by the upload status of files.

Everything works properly, but since I'm using `CloudKit`, the `perRecordProgressBlock` method gives me chunk-positions of the upload status instead of smooth progress feedback.

So far so good, but since I'm using that `perRecordProgressBlock` as a data source of my `UIProgressView`, the progress goes something like `0.0`, `0.15`, `0.75`, `0.99`, and so, the progress goes up block-by-block and I want to make that transition smoother.

When it goes from `0.15` to `0.75`, instead of jumping straight to `0.75`, can I make it animate to that position? Making it smoother?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `animated: true` when modifying the progress.

```
progressView.setProgress(0.99, animated: true)
```

If you want to set a custom transition time, set `animated` to `false` and put the code inside a `UIView` `animate` block.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.35) {
    self.progressView.setProgress(0.99, animated: false)
}
```

Comment: It doesn't smooth the progress for me